# How can the distance metric of two different metric spaces be comparable?

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

I come from a machine learning background and recently was working on understanding self normalizing networks. It requires me to know the proof of banach fixed-point theorem which needs me to know contraption mapping which got me to its wikipedia page. By now you know i deserve a mathematical layman treatment in this

I get the idea of contraction mapping when the transformation is from $M \rightarrow M$ and the distance metric remains the same, but:

On the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) of contraption mapping it says

> More generally, the idea of a contractive mapping can be defined for maps between metric spaces. Thus, if $(M,d)$ and $(N,d')$ are two metric spaces, then ${\displaystyle f:M\rightarrow N}$ is a contractive mapping if there is a constant ${\displaystyle k<1}$ such that
>   ${d'(f(x),f(y))\leq k\,d(x,y)} $

It eludes me how are the things getting compared for  two different metric spaces. what does it even mean when we say $d(.) > d^\prime(.)$ one would think these are two different distance metrics and hence not comparable

Comment: But you see, it isn't the elements of the different metric spaces that are being compared. In one metric space, the metric allows you to calculate the distance between any two points - this gives you a bunch of numbers. In the other metric space, its metric is calculating the distance between any two of its points - this is giving you a new bunch of numbers. Then you can certainly compare two numbers, one from each of the two bunches.

Comment: The definition of contraction should contain "for all $x,y\in M$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Ryan's comment: A metric $d$ defines the distance between two points. Distances are non-negative real numbers. So while $x, y \in M$, the distance between them, $d(x,y)$ is just a real number.

$f$ is by assumption a map which assigns points in $N$ to points in $M$. So, while $x, y \in M, f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are in $N$. And therefore the metric $d'$ on $N$ can measure the distance between them. And again, that distance $d'(f(x), f(y))$ is just a non-negative real number.

As they are both non-negative real numbers, we can do anything we want to do with them that is defined on non-negative real numbers. We could add them together, we could multiply them, we could raise one to the power of the other. In particular, we can compare one to the other to see which is larger.

Since you came at this while researching the Banach fixed point theorem, be aware that while a map between any two metric spaces can be a contraction, this theorem only applies to maps from a metric space to itself. A map $f$ from $M$ to $N$ may or may not be a contraction, but it can only have a fixed point if $M$ and $N$ intersect (since a fixed point would have to be in both of them). The Banach fixed point theorem only guarantees a contraction $f$ has a fixed point if $f$ maps $M$ to itself, and $M$ is complete (has no holes).

Comment: so if i define one metric space, $T1$, as the difference between masses of two objects in kilograms and another metric space, $T2$, as the difference between masses of two objects in pounds then $T2 \rightarrow T1$ is a contraction mapping?

Comment: You've described metrics, not metric spaces. A metric space also includes the space (the collection of objects to which the metric can be applied). And those two qualify as metrics only if that space does not contain any two objects of the same weight. Whether the identity map considered from $T_1 \to T_2$ is a contraction depends on whether you consider $1 \text{ lb} < 1\text{ kg}$ or $1\text{ lb} = 1\text{ kg}$. In the former case (which is how one usually compares unitized quantities), no it is not a contraction. In the latter case, yes, it is a contraction, but of no use.

Comment: The fixed point theorem does not apply to that case because it is about maps from a *metric space* to itself. And in that case, the fact that you are using different metrics makes the metric spaces different, even though the underlying sets for the spaces are the same.

Comment: thank you for the replies, respected sir! I know the fixed point theorem wont apply as i have changed the metric. I just wanted to know if i am correct about contraction mapping. let us define the metric space as 3 objects of 1kg, 2kg and 4kg each and the metric being as i defined above. Am i right in concluding that  mapping $T2 \rightarrow T1$ would be a contraction mapping with the best lipschitz constant equal to 0.454? @Paul Sinclair

Comment: As I already said, that depends on how you are defining the comparison. Normally when one compares measures that include units such as "kilograms" and "pounds", the comparison is done by the definition of the unit. E.g., $2\text { lb} < 1\text{ kg}$. The idea of proclaiming that $2\text { lb} > 1\text{ kg}$ because $2 > 1$ is just silly. By this realization, your map is an isometry, not a contraction. However, mathematically, you can drop the units and just consider the two metrics to give pure numbers. The result is a contraction. It is just not a useful one.

Comment: Thank you. You were very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: $d'(f(x),f(y))$ is a real number and $k\, d(x,y)$ is a real number, hence they are compared using the order relation on the real numbers.